# search box for my main site and sub-domain

Tags: search, button

Is there anyway possible besides Google custom search to create a search button that looks inside my main domain and sub-domain?

```
<div id="search-icon">
<div id="search-icon-icon"><div class="icon"></div></div>
<form method="get" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"  role="search">
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either setup your own search engine using Solr or Elasticsearch or similar, or use hosted services such as

- [Swiftype](https://swiftype.com/)
- [Searchbox](http://www.searchbox.com/)